# Creating data frame from dictionary where row names is key of the dictionary in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dictionary that looks like this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd 
In [2]: mydict = {'foo':0.3, 'bar':0.55}
```

What I want to to do is to create a data frame that looks like this:

```
bar 0.55
foo 0.3
```

What's the right way to do it?  I tried this

```
In [5]: pd.DataFrame(mydict, index=[0])
Out[5]: 
    bar  foo
0  0.55  0.3
```

Note that we literally wanted to use 'DataFrame' not 'Series', because
later we need to merge them.

Comment: Have you looked at [pandas.from_dict](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict) ?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index')` is something you are looking for?

Comment: It'd also help if your `dict` was valid syntax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended method is to use [`from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict) which is preferable to transposing after creation IMO:

```
In [21]:

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index')
df
Out[21]:
        0
bar  0.55
foo  0.30
```

Answer (score 2):

Just transpose it after you've created the DataFrame:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd 
In [2]: mydict = {'foo':0.3, 'bar':0.55}
In [3]: pd.DataFrame(mydict).T
```